# Error: 'NotificationsData' is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, use-effect

I want to map data which I've received in **Notifications** useState hook. But the problem is console showing me the following error

> 'NotificationsData' is not defined

I'm receiving data in Notifications hook successfully but don't know how to map that data. I've searched about the return statement and cleanup in useEffect but I didn't understand how do I implement that on my case.

### Component.jsx

```
useEffect(() => {
        
        const NotificationsData=()=>{
            return(
                <>
                    {
                        Notifications.map((value)=>{
                            <h1>{value}</h1>
                        })
                    }
                </>
            )
        }
        
    }, [Notifications])


return (
        <>
            <Header />
            <Container fluid>
                <Row>
                    <Col className="my_body">
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <NotificationsData />
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
            <Footer />
        </>
    )
```

Comment: So, how can I solve this issue??

Answer (score 1):

React component don't know what is NotificationsData because you declare it inside the useEffect scope.

create a new component called NotificationsData and then import it and render it in the Parent component (current one).

it should work.

Comment: Error is removes but map is not showing me any data on h1 element. I'm trying...

Answer (score 1):

`NotificationsData` isn't recognised as a component because you've included it within the scope of the `useEffect` method. Move it outside instead and pass in the data from your state as props.

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const data = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];

// Mock API function to return some data
function getData() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => res(data), 1000);
  });
}

// Your component. Pass in the notification data as props.
function NotificationsData({ data }) {
  return data.map(el => <h1>{el}</h1>);
}

function Example() {

  const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState([]);

  // Fetching some data and setting the state
  useEffect(() => {
    getData().then(data => setNotifications(data));
  }, []);

  // If there's nothing in state return a div or spinner
  if (!notifications.length) return <div>Loading</div>;

  // Otherwise return your component passing in the state
  return <NotificationsData data={notifications} />;

};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: I tried your code but its start giving me the error of [TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined]

Comment: Then you need to add the code you're using to get your data and set your state to your question.

Comment: I got hint from your code and try to code in a different way and got required result. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to access NotificationData coz it is encapsulated inside useEffect,Try defining it outside useEffect that would work.

Comment: yes I did according to Andy code but it start showing the the error I mentioned above in Andy comments

Comment: Try console.logging data I am pretty sure it must be an array not object try getting rid of NotificationsData({data}) instead NotificationsData(data)